# C++ error compilation C2275 when using enum in struct

Tags: c++, compilation, struct, typedef

I try to compile this code with Windows 8 SDK :

```
typedef struct {
    enum { red, blue, green } eColor;
    /* other params here */
} StMyStruct;

void Myfunction(StMyStruct *pst) 
{
    if (pst->eColor==StMyStruct.red) {
        /* some code here */
    }

}
```

But I get this error on line **if pst->eColor==StMyStruct.red** :

> error C2275: 'StMyStruct' : illegal use of this type as an expression

Any idea how to fix it ?

I compile this code successfully with Windows SDK 7, error happen only with Windows 8 SDK.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `StMyStruct::red`.

Also, you don't need the `typedef`, that is mainly used when developing C -- in C++, you can refer to a struct and class name directly.

Comment: Maybe VC++ needs that the struct has a name: try with `struct StMyStruct {...};` and then `StMyStruct::red`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why this compiles with SDK7 but I think the enum values are static members of `StMyStruct` so should be addressed via `StMyStruct::`

```
typedef struct {
    enum { red, blue, green } eColor;
} StMyStruct;

void Myfunction(StMyStruct *pst) 
{
    if (pst->eColor==StMyStruct::red) {
        /* some code here */
    }
}
```

Compiles cleanly for me with GCC and Visual Studio.

Comment: Hmm, not sure then as that fixes it on all the compilers I have access to. (Have now tried Comeau and Clang with the same result.)